# Doing logistic directly to analyse factors

Tags: regression, logistic

Is it correct to do logistic regression analysis directly to find out factors related to a disease without doing a bivariate analysis first?

Comment: Welcome to cv, Nisha! Your question is very general - do you have a particular case on mind? What exactly do you mean by bivariate analysis? Exploring the effect of single variables on the outcome?

Comment: The dependent variable is having the disease or not. I have 12 independent factors which are also categorical. I wanted to know whether I can directly go for logistic regression to analyse those 7 categorical factors without performing chi-square test initially. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - could you please edit your question and add this information?

Comment: The chi-square test you suggest, do you mean looking at the 2x12 (2x7?)contingency table?

Comment: Yes 2X2 contingency tables for the 12 factors. Is it a must to do this and then go for logistic regression instead of performing logistic directly . Thank you very much.

Comment: All the independent variables I have used, have been identified as factors in the literature,  so I need to include all of them in the logistic regression.  So is there any requirement that I need to perform bivariate analysis every time before performing multivariate analysis as it is being done routinely? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it is not required. Is it usually done in your field / lab / institution?

Comment: Thank you very much